# LiteIDE for Go: Playground Errors

Tags: go, liteide

I am using Mac OS X version X27.2.1of liteIDE.

I am able to build and run .go files fine however when I try to run code in the playground, I get the error:

```
"Error: Process failed to start"
```

[image]

Here is my setup, which works great when building and running .go files:

[image]

How can I fix?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are editing the darwin64-local.env file , but actually using the system.env file (the one selected in the drop down on the top toolbar). make sure you are using the correct file.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.